# JsInterop wrapping a javascript function property

Tags: javascript, gwt, wrapper, gwt-jsinterop

I am working with GWT 2.8, and I am working on a wrapper for a javascript library.

One of the properties of a javascript class I am trying to wrap is a function. I would like the wrapper to work as closely as possible to the native javascript. How do I go about wrapping a JsProperty that is a javascript function?

Details:
The javascript class has a property that is a function that is called when a specific event is triggered. I would like to be able to write a labmda function in Java, and assign it to this property, which would then run in javascript.

Comment: See [Implement Javascript Function Callback with GWT JsInterop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499407/implement-javascript-function-callback-with-gwt-jsinterop) question.

Answer (score 3):

As Adam said (and explained in more detail in the other post), you can expose a @JsProperty with a @JsFunction type.

```
@JsType(isNative=true) public class Foo {
    @JsFunction public static interface BarFn {
        Object invoke(Object... args);
    }
    @JsProperty public BarFn bar;
}
```

My recommendation to learn JsInterop is to explore other projects like: [OpenLayers JsInterop wrapper](https://github.com/TDesjardins/gwt-ol3), [Elemental2 source code](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.google.elemental2%22), or [explore github](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Agwt%20topic%3Ajsinterop). Elemental2 has the whole browser API so there are plety of examples, it is a really good place to find examples. JsInterop documentation [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit?usp=sharing).