# How to call a JavaScript function from GWT with jsInterop?

Tags: javascript, gwt, gwt-jsinterop

I tried the exampels in the docu https://docs.google.com/document/d/10fmlEYIHcyead_4R1S5wKGs1t2I7Fnp_PaNaa7XTEk0/edit# 
in the section @JsFunction but it gives only ideas to call java function from javascript.

I have a javascript file included in my GWT app with the following code:

```
var client = new Circuit.Client({
    client_id: '78cafde2f6854ad5ad80a67c532687bc',
    scope: 'READ_USER_PROFILE,READ_CONVERSATIONS',
    domain: 'circuitsandbox.net'
});

function startLogon() {
    client.logon()
      .then(user => console.log('Logged on as ' + user.displayName))
      .then(client.addEventListener('itemAdded', item => console.log('itemAdded event received:', item)))
      .then(client.getConversations)
      .then(conversations => {
         console.log('Retrieved ' + conversations.length + ' conversations');
    return client.addTextItem(conversations[0].convId, 'Hello World');
       })
      .then(item => console.log('Msg sent on ' + (new Date(item.creationTime)).toString()))
      .catch(console.error);
}
```

Now i want to call the function 'startLogon()' - my be with a wrapper - from my app using jsInterop annotations. I tried the two following examples without any success:

[Implement Javascript Function Callback with GWT JsInterop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499407/implement-javascript-function-callback-with-gwt-jsinterop)

[JsInterop wrapping a javascript function property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45699157/jsinterop-wrapping-a-javascript-function-property)

I have to say, that my JavaScript knowledge is very bad.

Can someone give me a code example?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @EJoshuaS because GWT compiles Java into comparable JS, and that is what the question is about.

Comment: Can you clarify what the return value is? it is a Promise, that you'll use in your Java code? or will you just call `startLogon()` in Java and then be done?

Answer (score 7):

Add this static method to any class.

```
@JsMethod(namespace = GLOBAL)
public static native void startLogon();
```

This will work, although you cannot do anything with the returned promise. If you want to use the returned promise I recommend adding elemental2 and use `Promise startLogon()` instead so you can consume it like this:

```
startLogon().then(
    success -> { console.log("success", success); return null; },
    failure -> { console.log("failure", failure); return null; });
```